# Accessing methods across a parallel inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I've looked all over to find the answer to my simple issue, but I'm probably just not understanding the solutions provided, or I'm not searching under the right terms. I have a parallel inheritance hierarchy, with two abstract base classes, each with potentially many children. Pseudo-UML:

```
       Node -----------> NodeData
        ^                   ^
        |                   |
        |                   |
    SpecialNode -----> SpecialNodeData
```

Since an object of type `Node` has a reference to an object of type `NodeData`, when `SpecialNode` wants to access a method unique to `SpecialNodeData`, it can't. I understand the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I'd love to get rid of the inheritance altogether, but not sure how and still keep the functionality. I appreciate any insight (maybe a link to a tutorial that helps with object oriented design issues like this?)

Sample Code:

```
interface NodeData {
    // methods
}

class Node {
    protected NodeData data;

    public Node(NodeData data) {
        this.data = data;
}

    // methods that use the generic NodeData
}

class SpecialNodeData implements NodeData {
    int x;

    public SpecialNodeData(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    /* Method unique to SpecialNodeData */
    public int getx() {
        return this.x;
    }

    // methods to implement generic NodeData
}

class SpecialNode extends Node {

    public SpecialNode(int x) {
        super(new SpecialNodeData(x));
    }

    public int getX() {
        return data.getX(); // gives Eclipse a sad face:
                            // "the method getX() is undefined for the type NodeData"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to handle this. Two come immediately to mind, one involving generics and the other involving covariant return types. I propose the latter:

```
class Node {
    // change this:
    private NodeData data;
    // add this:
    protected NodeData getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}

class SpecialNode extends Node {
    // add this:
    protected SpecialNodeData getData() {
        return (SpecialNodeData)(super.getData());
    }
    // change this:
    public int getX() {
        return getData().getX();
    }
}
```

This leverages Java's ability to have overridden methods be defined with covariant return types.

Comment: Generics was my first thought. Didn't know about the covariant return types in Java.  That's cool!

Comment: @MikeParkhill: Just FYI, methods and constructors can also have covariant exception types. See the Java 7 JLS, section 8.4.8.3 for details.